# "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" - duplicate files?

Tags: python, file, invalid-argument, oserror

Trying to create backup for my files:

```
name = input("Enter the name:" (\"/\" to quit)\n>>>")
name += ".vcblr"
write_file(name, ([], [], [], []))

def write_file(file, content) -> None:

    file = open(f"PythonVocabulary/{file}", "wb")
    pickle.dump(content, file)

    file = open(f"PythonVocabulary/backup/{file}", "wb")
    pickle.dump(content, file)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "PythonVocabulary/backup/<_io.BufferedWriter name='PythonVocabulary/german.vcblr'>"
```

Is the problem in duplicating files?

Comment: Don't you see `<_io.BufferedWriter name='PythonVocabulary/german.vcblr'>` ? `file` isn't a string, isn't a filename, but a BufferedWriter object. Please [edit] and share the code calling that method and the definition of the given file `variable`

Comment: @azro On closer inspection, the `file` parameter is getting overwritten by the return value of `open`. So it looks like this could be solved by renaming the parameter `filename` and using that in the f-strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like making a [mre], which can help catch typos like this.

Comment: Just to be clear, `<>` aren't allowed in filenames on Windows.

Comment: Sidenotes: Best practice for opening files is using `with` like `with open(fname) as f: pickle.dump(...)`. It's covered in the official tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). And I'd use a different name for the second file, like, say, `with open(...) as file_backup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwritting `file` with result of `open`. So use different variable names, and use `with` so the file descriptor is closed automatically

```
def write_file(filename, content) -> None:
    with open(f"PythonVocabulary/{filename}", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(content, file)

    with open(f"PythonVocabulary/backup/{filename}", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(content, file)
```